# MYSQL Custom Schedule for Scheduled Event

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a custom schedule for a scheduled event?

Desired outcome run an event at a specific time if scenario is met

1st day of month 00:01:00

last day of moth 23:59:00

All other days 18:00:00

Ex

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS new_event
ON SCHEDULE
AT CASE
       WHEN CURDATE() = DATE(FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01'))
       THEN '00:01:00'
       WHEN CURDATE() = LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
       THEN '23:59:00'
       ELSE '18:00:00'
   END + INTERVAL 1 DAY
DO
```

When trying to create the event it's throwing the follow error :
Error Code: 1525. Incorrect AT value: 'NULL'

Comment: Create 3 events and test in the code.

Comment: I can resolve the issue by adding an if statement within the event where if the date / time parameters are met then execute the code and running the event hour or so. I still would like to know if the question illustrated is possible

Comment: It’s not, sql is really poor at scheduling

Comment: Create SP and 3 separate events which calls it. Or create an event which is executed each minute, check current datetime at its start, and exit if the datetime is not matched starting condition.

Comment: SQL was found not for scheduling...